# Turn off an observer while creating model instances with FactoryGirl in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to turn off a model's observer (with after_create action) while creating an object with FactoryGirl.create ?

I'd like to create a bunch of objects before starting my tests but the observer brakes the process. So I want to have it switched off before the real testing started.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code, there might be an alternative way to do what you're trying to do. AFAIK you can't disable observers, you could possibly stub out the callbacks but that probably won't affect observers.

Comment: @spullen, what about `ActiveRecord::Base.observers.disable :all`? Would it work?

Comment: Yeah that should. Didn't know that you could turn off observers like that. Good to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems it is possible to disable all observers (or a specific one) across an application. Used the code below to switch it off/on while constructing an observed object.

```
 FactoryGirl.define do

      factory :user do
        association :status, :factory => :user_status

        before(:create) do
          ActiveRecord::Base.observers.disable :user_observer
        end

        after(:create) do
          ActiveRecord::Base.observers.enable :user_observer
        end
      end
 end
```